# Repeated text counter for each code that gives me the sum as a result in excel

Tags: excel, sum, counter

I have an excel that have a column that contains the code of each truck, and a column that have the level of infraction that each truck have made (based on the date), the level of infraction are three: mild, severe and intolerable.
I want to make another column that counts the level of infraction of each truck (based on each trucks code ) and based on the category of the infraction, is there any formula that I can use? I have tried with The function ‘=count’ but any well results, please help. I post an image showing an example of what i need [image]

Comment: A pivot table should do what you are asking if I understand correctly.

Comment: but the problem is i dont have any data in the columns where i have to make the counter

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(CZ$2:CZ$9,CZ2,DA$2:DA$9,DA2)`

Comment: If you want it sequential instead of a single total use `=COUNTIFS(cz$2:cz2,cz2,da$2:da2,da2)`

Comment: I dont know why it shows me this error: #¿NAME? , when copying that function , help please

Comment: You need to translate it to your regional language in Excel

Comment: thank you Warcupine for your answer, it works!!